# LINQ to Entity JOIN unexpected result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity

I have the following three entity classes:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public override string Id { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(false)]
        [DisplayName("Is Active?")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }



 public class Reseller : Organisation
    {

        //public List<EmailAddress> EmailAdresses { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public override string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        public List<Client> Clients { get; set; }

        public List<ResellerUserConnector> Users { get; set; }

    }

public class ResellerUserConnector
    {
        public ResellerUserConnector() { }

        public ResellerUserConnector(string userId) 
        {
            this.UserId = userId;
        }

        public Int64 Id { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public Int64 ResellerId { get; set; }

        public Reseller Reseller { get; set; }
    }
```

Logically, a `Reseller` can have zero or more `ApplicationUsers`.  Due to certain constraints, however, we are not allowed to have `Reseller` as an `ICollection<ApplicationUser>` property.  EF also can not deal with storing an `ICollection<string> property`.  Therefore I created the "associative" entity `ResellerUserConnector`.

I am, however, unsuccesful in retrieving the list of ApplicationUser instances for a given `Reseller` (although a direct glance at the database reveals that the values and keys are properly being stored in the db).

Here is the LINQ to Entity code which fails to retrieve the `List<ApplicationUser>` instance for a given `Reseller`.

```
List<ApplicationUser> users = (from u in identityDb.Users
                         join ru in r.Users on u.Id equals ru.UserId
                         select u).ToList<ApplicationUser>();
```

I'm a LINQ noob so please help a fella out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ids = r.Users.Select(c => c.UserId).ToList();    
List<ApplicationUser> users =
                        (from u in identityDb.Users
                         where ids.Contains(u.Id)
                         select u).ToList<ApplicationUser>();
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  Will mark it as answer as soon as I am allowed to ;)